# SAPUI5 - Sap.m.RadioButton Value Field?

Tags: sapui5

`sap.m.RadioButton` has got only `Text` attribute and does not have a `Value` attribute. 
While I can work around this by using custom data, is there anything I am missing?  `sap.ui.commons.RadioButton` has got a `key` field.

Also, what is good way to bind a value to a Radio Button Group(with `sap.m.Radiobutton` controls) in XML View

Comment: It is difficult to understand what is really being asked.. can you post some code of what you have already tried and what is it that you're looking to fix?

Comment: Could you describe your use case so that we know what you want to do with a value attribute.

Comment: Hi Tim, I have a sap.m.RadioButton group and i want to pass value for selected item in the group. Display Text is not the same as value to be passed.

Answer (score 0):

The "selected" property of sap.m.RadioButton is what you are looking for. [Documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.RadioButton.html)